# Access TransferSpreadsheet Export with Run-time Error 3434

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime-error, ms-access-2010

Hi Friends at stack overflow

I find my self dealing with a very peculiar error.

In access, I click on a button and a table is exported to an excel file.

I manipulate this excel file and add more data, then I upload it sucessfully into the table, when I want to export  the data for a second time I get an error

> "cannot expand name range" error number 3434

[image]

please find below my code, and what I am missing? I cant seem to find the root cause of the error

```vb
Private Sub CmdExportRNS_Click()

    On Error GoTo HandleError

    Dim fullPath As String

    fullPath = CurrentProject.path
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "ExceptionRNS", _
      CurrentProject.path & "\" & "myfile" & Format(Now(), " mm dd yyyy"), True
    MsgBox "File was Exported Successfully"

HandleExit:
   Exit Sub

HandleError:
   MsgBox Err.Description & " " & Err.Number
   Resume HandleExit
End Sub
        
Private Sub CmdRNSUpload_Click()
    On Error GoTo HandleError
    
    Dim file As Variant
    Dim query As String
    Dim tableNEW As String
    Dim tableDD As String
       
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
     
    file = Forms("SelfServe").Controls("fileNameRNS").Value
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM ExceptionRNS"
   
    If file = "" Then
        Forms("SelfServe").Controls("fileNameRNS").Value = ""
        MsgBox "No file selected"
        GoTo HandleExit:
    End If
     
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
                             "ExceptionRNS", file, True

    Forms("SelfServe").Controls("fileNameRNS").Value = ""
    
    MsgBox "Exception List Upload it successfully"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

HandleExit:
    Exit Sub

HandleError:
    MsgBox Err.Description & "Something went wrong, file failed to upload"
    Resume HandleExit
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd suggest that you turn off your specific error handling. Then you should be able to see at which line excatly you get the error. I'd also suggest that you make sure that the excel file you export to is closed.

Comment: Export data to workbook then import from same workbook - why?

Comment: HI, the exact line that throws an error is this one DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "ExceptionRNS", _
      CurrentProject.path & "\" & "myfile" & Format(Now(), " mm dd yyyy"), True

Let me try to have all excel files closed.

Also, The reason why the excel file is exported and updated is because the MAcro USers need to add records every quarter, and then upload them back to the table. 

Thank you for your help

Comment: At the end, I haven't been able to fix the issue. So I used a function I found Online https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/access/import-export-excel/

Comment: Still puzzled as why DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport doesn't work for me